# Lord Buddha descending from heavens?

Tags: the-buddha, reference-request, iconography

This question is about these images:

[image]  [image] [image]

This incident (depicted) happened after Lord Buddha visited a certain Deva realm.

- Can someone provide any sutta or sutra reference?
- If you can, please explain the event and the drawings?

Comment: Can someone tell me  why the down votes happen? Please leave a comment before you down vote.

Comment: I don't know why people are down voting this question, I am only asking for sources and explanations.

Answer (score 3):

One of those pictures is shown on this page: [Lhabab Duchen – the Day Buddha Descended from Tushita Heavens](https://buddhistartnews.wordpress.com/2013/12/04/lhabab-duchen-the-day-buddha-descended-from-tushita-heavens/):

> This article from Bhutan Journals describes the iconography of the Buddha Shakyamuni Descending from Tushita Heavens to the Earth.

A version of this story is told/included in [the Dhammapada-aṭṭhakathā (verse 181)](http://www.tipitaka.net/tipitaka/dhp/verseload.php?verse=181):

> On return from the Tavatimsa deva world, the Buddha uttered Verse (181) of this book at Sankassanagara, in reply to Thera Sariputta's words of welcome.

There's a more detailed version of this story somewhere else (I don't know where), for example Wikipedia's [Lhabab Duchen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lhabab_Duchen) article includes details about a "triple ladder" (shown in all the pictures):

> He was exhorted by his follower and representative Maudgalyayana to return, and after a long debate and under a Full Moon agreed to return. He returned to earth a week later by a special triple ladder prepared by Viswakarma, the god of machines. This event is considered to be one of the eight great deeds of the Buddha.